# aframe video play pause

Tags: three.js, aframe

I'm adding videos dynamically at runtime so I can't use the asset manager.

I'm trying to use `a-video` and then play/pause it.

I tried creating a videoEl and using that as the src

```
 this._videoPlayer = document.createElement('video')
 this._videoPlayer.id = 'video'
 this._videoPlayer.onloadeddata = this.onLoaded.bind(this)
 this._videoEl.setAttribute('src', this._videoPlayer)
```

or

```
 this._videoEl.setAttribute('src', '#video')
```

But the video isn't recognised as an asset

I then thought about using `THREE.VideoTexture(this._videoPlayer)` however I can't work out where to set the texture on a `a-plane` material.

Any idea how I would go about adding a video to aframe using a simple videoElement rather than the asset manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to append the video to the DOM if using selector.

Use `.setAttribute('material', 'src', VIDEO)` if it's a plain entity.

```
this._videoPlayer = document.createElement('video')
this._videoPlayer.id = 'video'
this._videoPlayer.onloadeddata = this.onLoaded.bind(this)
document.body.appendChild(this._videoPlayer);  // Append to DOM.
this._videoEl.setAttribute('material', 'src', '#video')
```

The video element can also be accessed if you just set a raw URL, and then `el.getObject3D('mesh').material.map.image`.